# Errors running julius.jconf in Ubuntu 18.04 command line

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-18.04, julius-speech

I have installed julius according to the Quick Run instructions on their [git repo](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius), but am getting mixed results that never run. However, when running the Quickstart suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/issues/82) I have been able to get the program running.

Using the command meant to recognize an audio file included with the "official" julius demo, `../julius/julius/julius -C mic.jconf -dnnconf dnn.jconf -input mic`, I get the following errors:

```
STAT: include config: julius.jconf
Stat: para: parsing HTK Config file: wav_config
Warning: para: "SOURCEFORMAT" ignored (not supported, or irrelevant)
Warning: para: TARGETKIND skipped (will be determined by AM header)
Stat: para: TARGETRATE=100000.0
Warning: para: "SAVECOMPRESSED" ignored (not supported, or irrelevant)
Warning: para: "SAVEWITHCRC" ignored (not supported, or irrelevant)
Stat: para: WINDOWSIZE=250000.0
Stat: para: USEHAMMING=T
Stat: para: PREEMCOEF=0.97
Stat: para: NUMCHANS=26
Stat: para: CEPLIFTER=22
Warning: para: NUMCEPS skipped (will be determined by AM header)
Warning: no SOURCERATE found
Warning: assume source waveform sample rate to 625 (16kHz)
ERROR: m_options: wrong argument: "-dnnconf"
Try `-help' for more information.
```

The Quickstart runs on the mic using `julius -input mic -C dnn.jconf`, I have modified it to `julius -input mozilla.wav -C dnn.jconf` in the directory created for the julius demo, but get the error message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

It's clear that there is no problem receiving audio from the mic, but I am not sure where I'm going wrong on the julius-speech quick run. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was my lack of understanding in how to modify the `dnn.jconf` file. As of 4.5 the `dnn.jconf` should read:

```
feature_type MFCC_E_D_A_Z
feature_options -htkconf wav_config -cvn -cmnload ENVR-v5.3.norm -cvnstatic
num_threads 1
feature_len 48
context_len 11
input_nodes 528
output_nodes 7461
hidden_nodes 1536
hidden_layers 5
W1 ENVR-v5.3.layer2_weight.npy
W2 ENVR-v5.3.layer3_weight.npy
W3 ENVR-v5.3.layer4_weight.npy
W4 ENVR-v5.3.layer5_weight.npy
W5 ENVR-v5.3.layer6_weight.npy
B1 ENVR-v5.3.layer2_bias.npy
B2 ENVR-v5.3.layer3_bias.npy
B3 ENVR-v5.3.layer4_bias.npy
B4 ENVR-v5.3.layer5_bias.npy
B5 ENVR-v5.3.layer6_bias.npy
output_W ENVR-v5.3.layerout_weight.npy
output_B ENVR-v5.3.layerout_bias.npy
state_prior_factor 1.0
state_prior ENVR-v5.3.prior
state_prior_log10nize false
```

Then it will work exactly as the Quickstart lays out. See [this closed issue](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/issues/115) from the julius repo.